# Can't find ServiceClient

Tags: c#, wcf

I receive the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'ServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm just trying to instantiate the ServiceClient and it doesn't think it's apart of the service.

It was working before, but then I removed the default interface, added a folder, and then placed the new interface in that folder. This is what the structure of my service currently looks like:

[image: Login picture]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting the error on the client project or the service project? If on the client, try regenerating the Service Reference.

Comment: @AndyB It's the client. I originally tried updating the service reference. But I went ahead and removed it altogether, rebuilt the project, and added it again. But still received the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. When I removed the original interface and added a new one, the name of the client changed from what I was expecting it to be, to the name of the new interface. So I added the original interface back and named it what it was. Instead of letting the service inherit each interface, I'll have it inherit the main one and then the main one will inherit the rest. So we stay with just one client name.